# Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module'

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code sits in the repo and I'm in the main branch but it's only me from my team who's getting the error. Works fine for everyone else. The Python version we use is 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repo/script_name.py", line 5, in <module>
    import SomeModule1
  File "repo/SomeModule1.py", line 23, in <module>
    import SomeModule2 #im thinking this might be the cause because it errors out when we try to access a method from SomeModule2
  File "repo/SomeModule2.py", line 4, in <module>
    import SomeModule3
  File "repo/SomeMdule3.py", line 2, in <module>
    standard_library.install_aliases()
  File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/__init__.py", line 485, in install_aliases
    import test
  File "repo/lib/test.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "repo/lib/SomeModuleVault.py", line 4, in <module>
    import SomeModule4
  File "repo/lib/SomeModule4.py", line 12, in <module>
    @SomeModule2.method
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Is it because its trying to access a method from `SomeModule2` before the module finishes importing?

Comment: Right, nothing in SomeModule2.py past the `import SomeModule3` line has been executed yet.

Comment: I think your module file is out of date and doesn't have this method. Look for update of module from repository or get file from others manually and copy it to your source folder.